# Next.js 13 React 18 not auto reloading browser when code is saved

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am using the New Apple Mini M2 (MacOS Ventura 13). Have created React and Next.js projects. When I run the project and do some code changes it compiles code but does not reload the browser. Even if I manually reload the changes are not reflected.
I executed this command in mac: `sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=524288`. Restarted the terminal still no luck.

I found that the compilation itself is not happening.

Does anybody solved these issues in mac?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some configurational issue. Check if hot module replacement is enabled in your webpack configuration. Hot module replacement allows the web page to update automatically when you save changes to your code. In your Next.js project, your next.config.js file should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      });
    }
    config.resolve.modules.push(__dirname);
    return config;
  },
  experimental: { reactRefresh: true },
};
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. But my issue was different. On MacOS I moved the project to desktop and everything started to work. Also I have not ejected my project to look into webpack config.

Comment: No problem, Glad you found the solution.